# What is this 「お忘れ物ございませんように」

Tags: set-phrases, phrases

For full context, see here:
https://www.docdroid.net/XIK9pCk/img-20171020-0001-new.pdf#page=2

The sentence in question is taken from line 24-26:

> でも、日本のアナウンスははっきりわかるので役に立つし、「お忘れ物ございませんように」と丁寧な話し方から、日本語のいい勉強にもなります。

My attempt at translation:

> However, because I clearly understand the Japanese announcement, it is useful and because ***it*** ??「お忘れ物ございませんように」 ?? is a courteous way speaking, it becomes a good lesson in Japanese.

So, I basically can't make any sense of this 「お忘れ物ございませんように」in this context xD By browsing jisho for ございます　I found out that it is the teneigo for "to be, exist". How this ございます relates to ように and お忘れ物　I have no idea. The "it" in my translation is actually redundant, I think. I put it there to make my translation more comprehensible, it shall be a dummy for the for me incomprehensible 「お忘れ物ございませんように」 . But since I'm so utterly clueless about 「お忘れ物ございませんように」 , I might've used my dummy "it" in an inappropriate way (syntactically). If that's the case, I'm sorry ^^

Comment: I will parse the part you don't understand for you, but then you will figure out what they mean by yourself. お忘れ物ございませんように can be split into: お + 忘れ物 + ございません + ように. Now, figure out what they mean and post an answer to your questions.

Comment: Hmm, could it be "So that there aren't forgotten things"?

Comment: Yes. Just like an announcer in more natural English might say "Please take care not to leave (forget) any of your belongings". The phrase ends in ように which suggests that it would end with something like 「ご注意ください」

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「ございません」 is the respectful form of 「ありません」.  So it's equivalent to 「お忘れ物ありませんように」.  The 〜ように here is "so/such that", and is omitting any number of acceptable verbs, e.g. (注意)する.

So overall it is just

> (Please) make sure there are no forgotten items　→　(Please) make sure you don't leave anything behind

This is a common phrase to hear on trains/subways/etc. in Japan when the vehicle is approaching the next station or stop.